# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab to run my code. I was trying to fine tune resNext pre-trained model, but i kept getting the this error.

Error i am getting:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-701d4083f562> in <cell line: 12>()
     18         inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
     19         optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 20         outputs = model(inputs)
     21         loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     22         loss.backward()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_CUDA_addmm)
```

I tried following other stackoverflow solution to this error.

E.g.

1. "If you need to move a model to GPU via .cuda() , please do so before constructing optimizers for it. Parameters of a model after .cuda() will be different objects with those before the call.
   In general, you should make sure that optimized parameters live in consistent locations when optimizers are constructed and used."

In my code below, i did declare model.to(device) before declaring my optimizers

2. "Make sure to add .to(device) to both the model and the model inputs."

Checked, both my model and model inputs have .to(device)

My code is as follows:

```
# Load and modify the pretrained model
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnext50_32x4d', pretrained=True)
model = model.to(device)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 7) 

# Loss function and optimizer
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training and validation
num_epochs = 5
patience = 5
validation_loss_min = np.Inf
patience_counter = 0

train_losses = []
val_losses = []

total_start_time = time.time()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_start_time = time.time()
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs.cuda())
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)

    # Validation
    model.eval()
    validation_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in val_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            validation_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
    validation_loss = validation_loss / len(val_loader.dataset)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    val_losses.append(validation_loss)

    validation_accuracy = 100 * correct / total
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs} \t Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f} \t Validation Loss: {validation_loss:.4f} \t Validation Accuracy: {validation_accuracy:.2f}%')

    if validation_loss < validation_loss_min:
        print(f'Validation loss decreased ({validation_loss_min:.6f} --> {validation_loss:.6f}). Saving model ...')
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/content/drive/My Drive/FER-2013 Dataset/Model/modelV2.pt')
        validation_loss_min = validation_loss
        patience_counter = 0
    else:
        patience_counter += 1
        if patience_counter >= patience:
            print('Early stopping triggered.')
            break

total_end_time = time.time()
print(f'Total training time: {total_end_time - total_start_time:.2f} sec')
```

I can't figure out what is the mistake that is causing this error.

Comment: What is `device` defined as? Looks like the model and inputs are on different devices. The `cuda()` call put the inputs on the GPU, but maybe the `to(device)` call is using the wrong device. If `device` is `cuda` then you won't need the `inputs.cuda()` call since the code already called `inputs.to(device).

Comment: Thanks for replying! This is how device is defined as `device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")`

I printed the output of device, it is cuda.

I am sorry about the `input.cuda()` part, I forgot to change it back. Initially, it was `outputs = model(inputs)` but I kept getting the run time error, so i tried `inputs.cuda()`

Comment: I just tried to add `print("Device check:", inputs.device, labels.device, next(model.parameters()).device)` below `outputs = model(inputs.cuda())`, the output is cuda for all 3. This don't make sense that it is not working hmm

Comment: Please your code execution again by running all your code (from a new runtime if you use a notebook). Your code snippet works on my end. Check that both the inputs and the model's weights are on the same device (here gpu): you can check the first layer device with `model.conv1.weight.device`.

Comment: I tried "restart session and run all" and "disconnect and delete runtime", but both doesn't work. However, when I created a new notebook and copied the code over then somehow it started to work. Thank you for the input, it helped a lot. Also, I can't find the button to upvote your comment or make the green tick HAAHA.